# How to make my loop properly work and move on to the next after it's done it's work?

Tags: python, loops, sikuli-x

I'm trying to get my loop to check for one thing multiple times, and if a value surpasses another value, it ends and goes to the next loop.

What I have right now is this:

```
x = 1
a = 7
complete = False
while complete == False:
    click(Im using sikulix so theres an image of what its supposed to click here)
    x == x+1
    if x > a:
        complete == True
    else:
        complete == False
```

What doesn't work with this script is that the loop doesn't end, it just keeps going.
I've tried putting a `break` after the `complete == True` but it doesn't change anything.
What could I change to make this work as expected?

Comment: Typo: `==` is comparison, use `=` for assignment.

Comment: Why not `for x in range(1, a+1):`?

Comment: You need to learn basic debugging, like adding `print(x)` into the loop. Then you would have seen that you weren't incrementing properly. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Don't compare to True and False.  Do `while not complete:`.  It reads better.  Also, you can say `complete = x > a` instead of your if, but you can skip `complete` altogether by doing `while x <= a:`, and at that point you should just move to @Barmar's version.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: == is comparison, use = for assignment.

– Barmar

I did not know this, thanks!
(I'm still very new to coding)

Comment: But you did know it, because the first three lines of that code use `=` the right way for assignment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).